# need to identify species of this Leaf-footed bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

I found this bug in **Pune/India**. I checked many species of leaf-footed bugs, but none of them is matching this one. It was about 3cm long. It was not showing any movement.

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks similar to some *Leptoglossus* species -- not sure if that genus is in India or not...

Comment: I think you are right, can you identify species?? @theforestecologist